# If $A$ is an $n$ square matrix of rank $n-1$ then show that $\operatorname{adj}A \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, alternative-proof, matrix-rank

If $A$ is an $n$ square matrix of rank $n-1$ then show that $adjA \neq 0$

My attempt:
Since $A$ is an $n$-rowed square matrix of rank $n-1$,therefore at least one $n-1$ rowed minor of the matrix $A$ is not equal to zero. But every $n-1$ square minor of matrix $A$ is equal to in magnitude to the cofactor of some element in $|A|$. Hence at least one element in $|A|$ has its cofactor non zero. Therefore at least one element of $adj.A$ is not equal to zero. Hence $adj.A \neq O$.
Please provide me alternate proof of above problem. Thanks.

Comment: If adjugate is defined via cofactors, your proof is probably the most accessible if not the simplest. For a more natural proof, let $Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_{n-1}$ be a basis of the range of $A$ and let $y$ be outside the range. Then
$$
0\ne\det\left(Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_{n-1},y\right)
\color{red}{=}\det\left(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},\operatorname{adj}(A)y\right)
$$
and hence $\operatorname{adj}(A)\ne0$. However, the identity in red (which is more properly written as $Ax_1\wedge\cdots\wedge Ax_{n-1}\wedge y
=x_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_{n-1}\wedge \operatorname{adj}(A)y$) is usually not taught in class.